# Surfacecreated method not getting called at onResume for Android Surfaceview

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-animation

I am playing an animation by using runnable thread inside a surface view.  When I run the application for the first time, everything works fine and animation plays properly.  When I press back/home button and reopens the application, I am getting a Black Screen with no animations but the runnable thread works on the background which I confirmed using Log cat entry.

Also, I am overriding the back button press event and finish() is called inside the back button press event.

Can any one please help me out why surfacecreated method is not being called when I resume the application?

**Note :** When I use

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Inside the back button event instead of finish() method, the application works properly in onresume event.

Thanks in Advance, Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think，you must extend SurfaceView class and listen on surfaceChanged method。And in the method to draw again.
code:

```
class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{  
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        public MySurfaceView(Context context) {  
            super(context); 
            holder = this.getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this); 
        }  
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,  
                int height) {  
            //when surfaceChanged,i think you must make your view draw one time.

        }   
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
            //surfaceCreated
        }    
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {  
            //surfaceDestroyed
        }  

    }
```

Hope this can help you.